# Using List<Long> as parameter in Spring CrudRepository

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm working with spring and crud repositories. All works fine but when i do that query:

```
@Query("select distinct(a) from Attribute a where a.placeGroup.organization.id = ?1 and a.placeGroup.id = ?2 and a.attributeEntity = ?3 and a.id in ?4")
List<Attribute> findAllPlaceAttributesByIds(long organizationId, long groupId,
        Attribute.AttributeEntity type, Iterable<Long> ids);
```

I've got fallowing Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [4] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long]
```

Any ideas how can i solve this?

Comment: ids should be Long not Iterable

Comment: great but this should be List not 1 value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thing was that in some way this List contained Strings because of wrong Json cast.

Comment: Ok, you should consider deleting the question :)

Answer (score 0):

findAllPlaceAttributesByOrganizationAndPlaceGroupAndIdsIn(Orgaization organizationId, PlaceGroup groupId,
        Attribute.AttributeEntity type, Iterable ids)

should do the trick.

Comment: But what with rest of parameters? I want use organizationId, groupId and type also.

Comment: Sorry, I just thought you wanted to know about In query. I think for all the other params you need to change the method name and pass objects not id. I updated the answer. try that.